# Keywords: some and one before higher-order quantification

Tags: alloy

I have an Alloy specification representing a model transformation rules.. In the specification, I use higher-order quantification to specify rule matching. One strange thing is the analyzer works differently with "some" and "one", which I cannot understand.

For example, in the pred rule_enter[trans:Trans](see line 240), I use two higher-order quantification to encoding matching of the left and right side of a graph transformation rule.
***********************EXAMPLE****************************************

```
some e_check0:Acheck&trans.darrows, e_TP0:ATP&(trans.source.arrows-trans.darrows), e_PF10:APF1&trans.darrows, e_TR0:ATR&(trans.source.arrows-trans.darrows), e_F1R0:AF1R&trans.darrows |
let n_P0 = e_check0.src, n_T0 = e_TP0.src, n_R0 = e_TR0.trg, n_F10 = e_PF10.trg |
(n_P0 = e_check0.trg and n_P0 = e_TP0.trg and n_P0 = e_PF10.src and n_T0 = e_TR0.src and n_F10 = e_F1R0.src and n_R0 = e_F1R0.trg  and
n_F10 in NF1&trans.dnodes and
n_P0 in NP&(trans.source.nodes-trans.dnodes) and n_T0 in NT&(trans.source.nodes-trans.dnodes) and n_R0 in NR&(trans.source.nodes-trans.dnodes))

some e_crit0:Acrit&trans.aarrows, e_TP0:ATP&(trans.source.arrows-trans.darrows), e_PF20:APF2&trans.aarrows, e_TR0:ATR&(trans.source.arrows-trans.darrows), e_F2R0:AF2R&trans.aarrows |
let n_P0 = e_crit0.src, n_T0 = e_TP0.src, n_R0 = e_TR0.trg, n_F20 = e_PF20.trg |
(n_P0 = e_crit0.trg and n_P0 = e_TP0.trg and n_P0 = e_PF20.src and n_T0 = e_TR0.src and n_F20 = e_F2R0.src and n_R0 = e_F2R0.trg  and
n_F20 in NF2&trans.anodes and
n_P0 in NP&(trans.source.nodes-trans.dnodes) and n_T0 in NT&(trans.source.nodes-trans.dnodes) and n_R0 in NR&(trans.source.nodes-trans.dnodes))
```

---

Here I use the keyword "some". The Analyzer can work with a scope 10.

But if I use the keyword "one", the analyzer reports the following error with a scope 5:
***********************EXAMPLE****************************************

```
Executing "Check check$1 for 5 but exactly 1 Trans, exactly 2 Graph, exactly 1 Rule"
  Solver=minisat(jni) Bitwidth=0 MaxSeq=0 SkolemDepth=1 Symmetry=20
  Generating CNF...
.
Translation capacity exceeded.
In this scope, universe contains 89 atoms
and relations of arity 5 cannot be represented.
Visit http://alloy.mit.edu/ for advice on refactoring.
```

---

**MY QUESTION** is why the two quantification have different performances?

Answer (score 2):

`one` in alloy is encoded using set comprehension and the cardinality operator, e.g.,

```
one s: S | p[s]
```

is transformed to

```
#{s: S | p[s]} = 1
```

Set comprehension cannot be skolemized, so when the quantifier in question is higher-order, Alloy simply gives up.

Answer (score 1):

Higher-order quantifications are in general not allowed in Alloy. However, some *existential* quantifications (i.e., **some**) can be converted into solvable procedures through a process known as *skolemization*, which I believe does not apply to *uniqueness* quantifications (i.e., **one**). The process is briefly explained [here](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/quickguide/skolem.html) for a (first-order) Alloy example.

I wasn't able to process your example (sorry), but I would guess that is one such case.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a concrete answer for your example but generally it is more complex to encode `one` than `some`: Let's assume you have a set S that can maximally contain the elements a, b, c.

Alloy translates the problem to a SAT problem.
You can encode S in a SAT problem with 3 Boolean variables `xa`, `xb`, `xc` where `xa=TRUE` (resp. `FALSE`) means that a is in S (resp. not in S).

The statement `some S` can now easily encoded as the formula

```
xa \/ xb \/ xc
```

(with `\/` as logical or).

On the other hand, for `one` you need to encode additionally that if one of the variables `xa`, `xb`, `xc` is true, the others are false. E.g.

```
xa \/ xb \/ xc
xa => not( xb \/ xc )
xb => not( xa \/ xc )
xc => not( xa \/ xb )
```

In conjuctive normal form (CNF, that's what the SAT solver takes as input) you have the clauses:

```
xa \/ xb \/ xc
-xa \/ -xb
-xa \/ -xc
-xb \/ -xa
-xb \/ -xc
-xc \/ -xa
-xc \/ -xb
```

Maybe there are techniques to optimize that but you can see that `one` needs more clauses to be encoded than `some`.